How to create .ckpt/.pb file from .cfg and .weights files?
So I am using darknet and Yolo to try to generate a model and a checkpoint image classification model for tensorflow version 1.9:
I learned that It is possible to generate through 3 ways:

generate the .h5 version of it using darknet then convert it using
tensorflow save and load methods convert the .cfg and .weights files
of Yolo to .pb then to .ckpt
using either
https://github.com/thtrieu/darkflow/ or
https://github.com/jinyu121/DW2TF

I am using Python 2.7 for project comptability and tensorflow 1.9.
darkflow returns error when being built (through the cmd darkflow>python setup.py build_ext --inplace):
darkflow\cython_utils\cy_yolo2_findboxes.pyx:97:11: 'NMS' is not a constant, variable or function identifier

While DW2TF returns the following error (after running the cmd DW2TF>python main.py --cfg darknet19.cfg --weights darknet19.weights.txt --prefix DW2TF-yolov2-tiny-coco --output content):
DW2TF\main.py", line 56, in main
    tf.reset_default_graph()
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'reset_default_graph'

How to go about this issue given the restrictive setting of tensorflow and python versioning?
